# Chrome out of screen boundaries when it's maximized

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I'm using Xubuntu 21.04 and as you can see in the screenshot chrome window goes out of screen boundaries when I maximize it. Tried to change the theme (classic and gtk+) but got the same result. It's only happening for the chrome window, others are fine.

Is there someone who knows why and how can I fix this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just updated 21.10 to see if any changes will, still the same issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and the solution to it was to "Use system title bar and borders" under the settings on the "System Menu" on the upper-right hand corner in Chrome.

Navigate to settings -> appearance and the setting is in there.

As shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: fixed that way, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a chromium bug which appeared in version 95 or 96:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1261797
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1260821 (xfce specific)

As of now, it's not yet have been fixed.

As a temporary solution you can downgrade your Chrome version:

```sh
$ wget 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_94.0.4606.81-1_amd64.deb'
$ sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_94.0.4606.81-1_amd64.deb
```