# When maximized, Chrome bleeds into second monitor

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (Xubuntu) and have two monitors. After updating Google Chrome (to Version 95.0.4638.54), it bleeds into the next monitor whenever I maximize the window.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution here: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371473/chrome-out-of-screen-boundaries-when-its-maximized)

Comment: That is a workaround, not a solution. Still, for full screen use, it  is acceptable. Likely a bug with Chrome?